# I created my first hybrid app on MobileFist, now how to publish it to a real device?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I've just created my brand new - and simple - hybrid app using MobileFirst and JQuery Mobile.
I can preview it on the MobileFirst Console, but now the question is: How to deploy it to a real device?
Is there a way to easily export my hybrid app to and apk file? 
There are some mentions about the ApplicationCenter, is it needed to publish my app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a hybrid Android app using MobileFirst Studio you need to follow the steps to setup your Android environment.

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/setting-up-your-development-environment/setting-android-development-environment/

After you build your Android environment an Android project will be loaded into your eclipse workspace. To export this project as an .apk simply right click the project in your workspace **Android Tools** > **Export Signed Application Package...** and follow the export wizard. Alternatively you can follow the steps on how to export your signed application in http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing-eclipse.html

Comment: Thanks Yoel,
I'm already using MobileFirst Studio, one thing I noticed is that you can add environments to your MobileFirst hybrid project, this way I was able to preview my app in Android Studio.